# How to code a button to enter a value in a textbox on another form

Tags: c#, button, newforms

I have form 1 with 4 buttons when I click a button it opens a new form. Each button opens the same form but I want the corresponding button to enter specific values into two different text boxes on form 2.

Form 1 Button A; Form2 `textbox1= 400 textbox2 =0.4`

Form 1 Button B; Form2 `textbox1= 350 textbox2 =0.9`

Form 1 Button C; Form2 `textbox1= 700 textbox2 =0.6`

Form 1 Button D; Form2 `textbox1= USER DEFINED` `textbox2 = USER DEFINED`

How would I go about this

```
 //This is the current text
 // Form1:   
private void ButtonA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           Form2 numb = new form2();
           numb.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(numb_FormClosed);
           this.Hide();
           CalcForm.Show();
    }
```

Comment: You could create a parameterized constructor for the second form, to provide it with values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set the value of the required textBox from the first form like below, but before it make sure that you have set that textBox to be internal so that you can access it from first form(in the Form.Designer.cs):

```
internal System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
```

and

```
private void ButtonA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       Form2 numb = new form2();
       numb.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(numb_FormClosed);
       numb.textbox1.Text = "400";
       numb.textbox2.Text = "0.4";
       this.Hide();
       CalcForm.Show();
}
```

Another approach is to define parameterized constructor for Form2 and set the value of the TextBox in that constructor like below:

```
public Form2(string a,string b)
{
    textBox1.Text = a;
    textBox2.Text = b;
}
```

and

```
private void ButtonA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       Form2 numb = new form2("aaaa","bbbb");
       numb.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(numb_FormClosed);
       this.Hide();
       CalcForm.Show();
}
```

Comment: I did the parameterised way, and its worked! Thank you